# What is this snake / spear / projectile weapon the Yuuzhan Vong use?

Tags: star-wars, yuuzhan-vong

I've seen it in a few images, sometimes it's being used to stab at an opponent like a spear, sometimes it's being used as portrayed the image below.

I know they hate technology, so is this their version of standard infantry weapon?

I'm sure it's explained in the EU books, I just haven't read them yet.

[image]

Comment: You should take the time to read the New Jedi Order books. IMO, the Vong invasion was the best overall event since the "Heir to the Empire" trilogy. Not every book is perfect, but the overall story arc is epic.

Comment: @Omegacron Just in the middle of a different series of books atm man, can't break out of one series and jump into another, that's sacrilege!!

Comment: @Omegacron: If only the whole series was written by Aaron Allston and Mike Stackpole. Luceno did well. Denning, Tyers, etc., did their best to ruin a good arc. Even Williams and Dix, two Australian authors that I personally know, didn't perform well in the *Star Wars* universe. In their defence, they told me they had a LOT of editorial interference. I know Denning experienced some direct intervention from Lucas himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be their [Amphistaff](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Amphistaff).

Per Wookieepedia:

> Amphistaffs were genetically engineered serpentine creatures that served as the primary anti-personnel weapons of the Yuuzhan Vong.

They are their favored weapon. Wookieepedia explains how they are used:

> If a warrior captured an amphistaff as it left its polyp, the two were bound together and the amphistaff would loyally serve its new master in battle. Hand motions from the warrior coaxed the amphistaff to either harden or become pliable, for each had its own purposes. Amphistaffs had three distinct forms: a quarterstaff, a spear, or a whip. As a hardened spear with a poisonous head, the amphistaff could be hurled, further increasing its lethality. As a flexible whip, the amphistaff could trip or pin its target and even poison it. Amphistaffs were one of the most durable objects known, as not even lightsabers could cut through them. When used as a heavy staff, the serpent would endure blow after blow from the Jedi weaponry and remain unfazed. The amphistaff's edge—measured in atoms—slashed through flesh with no resistance. In the blink of an eye, the amphistaff could soften and wind around the lightsaber's blade, its venomous jaws snapping and tearing at the unfortunate victim's face. Because of its organic nature, these creatures were capable of recovering from virtually any wounds. Nigh indestructible, an amphistaff could only be killed by repeated blunt trauma to or removal of the head.

[image: A Yuuzhan Vong with an amphistaff]

Comment: Cheers Phantom, much appreciated! With a name like that though, I feel like I could of guessed it!

Comment: Good answer. You may want to add that each Vong warrior typically kept the staff "holstered" by having it coil around his arm. Simply by twitching an arm muscle, the amphistaff would go from coiled to the warrior's hand in a second.

Comment: I believe the amphistaff could also spit venom, and on at least one occasion it bit Corran Horn, putting him in a coma that Ganner Rhysode needed to save him from. It would be better to say "venomous bite" than "poisonous head," but hey, that's *Wookieepedia* for you. Great source of information, but with the occasional poor choice of language.

Comment: I envision a remote-control snake that swallowed some viagra.